# XML serializing with XmlWriter via StringBuilder is utf-16 while via Stream is utf-8?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, xml-serialization, stream

I was surprised when I encountered it, and wrote a console application to check it and make sure I wasn't doing anything else.

Can anyone explain this?

Here's the code:

```
using System;    
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var o = new SomeObject { Field1 = "string value", Field2 = 8 };

            Console.WriteLine("ObjectToXmlViaStringBuilder");
            Console.Write(ObjectToXmlViaStringBuilder(o));
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("ObjectToXmlViaStream");
            Console.Write(StreamToString(ObjectToXmlViaStream(o)));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static string ObjectToXmlViaStringBuilder(SomeObject someObject)
        {
            var output = new StringBuilder();
            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8, Indent = true };

            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(output, settings))
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeObject));
                var namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

                xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
                xmlWriter.WriteDocType("Field1", null, "someObject.dtd", null);
                namespaces.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);
                serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, someObject, namespaces);
            }

            return output.ToString();
        }

        private static string StreamToString(Stream stream)
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        public static Stream ObjectToXmlViaStream(SomeObject someObject)
        {
            var output = new MemoryStream();
            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8, Indent = true };

            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(output, settings))
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeObject));
                var namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

                xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
                xmlWriter.WriteDocType("Field1", null, "someObject.dtd", null);
                namespaces.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);
                serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, someObject, namespaces);
            }

            output.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            return output;
        }

        public class SomeObject
        {
            public string Field1 { get; set; }
            public int Field2 { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result:

ObjectToXmlViaStringBuilder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<!DOCTYPE Field1 SYSTEM "someObject.dtd">
<SomeObject>
<Field1>string value</Field1>
<Field2>8</Field2>
</SomeObject>
```

ObjectToXmlViaStream

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Field1 SYSTEM "someObject.dtd">
<SomeObject>
<Field1>string value</Field1>
<Field2>8</Field2>
</SomeObject>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When you create an `XmlWriter` around a `TextWriter`, the `XmlWriter` always uses the encoding of the underlying `TextWriter`. The encoding of a `StringWriter` is always UTF-16, since that's how .NET strings are encoded internally.

When you create an `XmlWriter` around a `Stream`, there is no encoding defined for the `Stream`, so it uses the encoding specified in the `XmlWriterSettings`.

Comment: See [MSDN XmlWriterSettings.Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.encoding.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

The most elegant solution for me is to write to a memorystream and then using encoding to encode the stream to whatever encoding is required.
like so

```
        using (MemoryStream memS = new MemoryStream())
        {
            //set up the xml settings
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = OmitXmlHeader;

            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlTextWriter.Create(memS, settings))
            {
                //write the XML to a stream
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, objectToSerialize);
                writer.Close();
            }
            //encode the memory stream to xml
            retString.AppendFormat("{0}", encoding.GetString(memS.ToArray()));
            memS.Close();
        }
```

where the encoding takes place at ....encoding.GetString(memS.ToArray())...

Answer (score 2):

Where possible, the XmlWriter uses the encoding of the underlying stream. It it wrote UTF-8 data to a stream it knew was UTF-16, you'd end up with a mess. Writing UTF-16 data to a UTF-8 stream also causes problems, especially for environments that use null terminated strings (like C/C++).

The StringBuilder/StringWriter presents a UTF-16 stream to the XmlWriter, so the XmlWriter ignores your requested setting and uses that.

In practise I usually don't emit the  header, that way I can use a StringBuilder underneath and save a few lines of code messing about with switching encodings.

Comment: Strictly speaking, a `Stream` doesn't have an encoding, it's just raw binary data... But the `TextWriter` used to write to the stream *does* have an encoding.

Comment: Thank you!
I didn't understand the remark about the header, though. Can you show some code?